# Microsoft Dynamics CRM RetrieveEntityChanges alongside it's Linked entities

Tags: rubygems, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Currently, i'm working on a project where we fetch data from Microsoft CRM using the Ruby gem [dynamics_crm](https://github.com/dovetail-studios/dynamics_crm)
the way that we execute this is by retrieving the changes using `RetrieveEntityChanges`, the problem with this is that i cant fetch the linked entities, but yes using the XMLBuilder, but it doesn't fetch the changes, my question is, anyone knows a way or have a XML example for use `RetrieveEntityChanges` and retrieve the linked entities at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RetrieveEntityChanges` doesn't work with linked entities, only with the entity specified inside the parameter `EntityName`

Comment: thanks for replying, this helps me a lot!